# Test if in range in R. Why does this not work?

Tags: r, range, logical-operators

```
> testRange <- range(1:10)
> 5 %in% testRange
[1] FALSE
```

My expectation is that 5 would be in the range 1:10. Why is this not the case? Am I missing something about what a range is in R?

A related question: why is this the case:

```
> testRange3 <- 1:10
> testRange4 <- range(1:10)
> 5 %in% testRange3
[1] TRUE
> 5 %in% testRange4
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: `range(1:10)` returns `c(1,10)` not all the integers 1 to 10. You want `5L %in% 1:10` to do a safe integer comparison. `5L` being the integer for 5 exactly, and `5` being a floating point number for 5.

Comment: Ok, that works, but why doesn't ```5L %in% testRange``` ?

Comment: Because you are asking `5L %in% c(1,10)` and 5 is neither equal to 1 or 10.

Comment: You may be looking for `{1,10}` instead of `range()`. This will give you the numbers from 1 to 10.

Comment: @MichaelPlazzer - I don't think that works in R.

Comment: ``` 5L %in% {1:10}```
 worked!!!!!
as did
```testRange2 <- {1:10}
5 %in% testRange2```

Comment: To reiterate what @thelatemail said, `range` gives you the min and max values of its argument, and neither of them is 5, so it's false. It seems you want to test something like  `5 >= testRange[1] & 5 <= testRange[2]`

Comment: @Thoughtcraft - the `{}` brackets don't do anything in this instance. The `:` is the key bit.

Comment: Oh I see. And that just brings me back to what I was doing before using range(). I wanted to use range instead of making a list because I thought it would be more efficient.

Comment: You are confusing the function in R with the function in python. Note that `range` in python 2 creates a list, not an iterable, so is not more efficient. `5 %in% 1:10` works as well.